# Could not iterate asynchrous function inside loop using MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am unable to call mongoDB callback function inside the loop. I am providing my array and code below.

```
[
    {
        "location": "NEW DELHI",
        "nos_of_fos": 15,
        "login_id": [
            "9619300317",
            "9619300343",
            "9619300338",
            "9619300351",
            "9619300322",
            "9619300316",
            "9619300323",
            "9619300328",
            "9619300341",
            "9619300309",
            "9619300310",
            "9619300329",
            "9619300353",
            "9619300356",
            "NORTH@oditeksolutions.com"
        ],

    },
    {
        "location": "North West Delhi",
        "nos_of_fos": 6,
        "login_id": [
            "9619300355"
        ],

    }
]
```

The above is my input array.

```
finalOut.forEach(function(listItem, index){
                    var remarkCount=0;
                    console.log('items',listItem['login_id']);
                    listItem['login_id'].forEach(function(item, index1){
                        Feedback.collection.countDocuments({login_id:item},function(cerr,cdocs){
                            if (!err) {
                                if (docs >0) {
                                    console.log('docsinner',cdocs);
                                    remarkCount+=parseInt(cdocs);
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    })
                    console.log('docsout',remarkCount);
                    finalOut[index]['total_remarks']=remarkCount;
                })
```

Here before finishing mongoDB checking for first iteration loop getting finished. Here I need to check one by one login_id value and only after finishing the mongoDB task new count will assign.

Comment: use promises instead

Comment: Can you update you answer.

Comment: please try this

Comment: @AshokMandal : No,its not working as expected.

Comment: @AshokMandal: you can check it.there is no `total_remarks` value there. and also no console message are executing.

Comment: is finalOut is a mongoose object ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187312/discussion-between-satya-and-ashok-mandal).

Answer (score 1):

```
finalOut.forEach(function(listItem, index) {
  var remarkCount = 0;

  var promises = listItem['login_id'].map(function(item, index1) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Feedback.collection.countDocuments({ login_id: item }, function(
        err,
        docs
      ) {
        if (!err) {
          if (docs > 0) {
            console.log('docsinner', docs);
            remarkCount += parseInt(docs);
          }
          resolve();
        }
        reject();
      });
    });
  });
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      finalOut[index]['total_remarks'] = remarkCount;
    })
    .catch(err => {});
});
```

Comment: there is no `total_remarks` value in the final array.